# Error in "if (reached.threshold < min.reached.threshold) {" : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I get the following error message :

```
Error in 
    "if (reached.threshold < min.reached.threshold) {" : 
     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

It occurs when I am using *tan hyperbolic activation* function in modeling a neural network architecture using **neuralnet** function in R

```
mymodel24 <- neuralnet(
    increaseScope~rsi10 + rsi14+ rsi20 + signal + roc12 + fastK + 
    wpr + bias3 + bias5 + bias10, 
    data=bseFinalData, hidden=c(3,2), err.fct="sse", 
    linear.output=TRUE, algorithm="backprop", 
    act.fct="tanh",                                   # <= this line
    threshold = 0.01, learningrate = 0.01, rep=3
)
```

It works well when I use `act.fct="logistic"`

Comment: That's an informative error: either `reached.threshold` or `min.reached.threshold`, or both, is missing (`NA`).

Comment: The problem is: we do not control directly "reached.threshold" or "min.reached.threshold". What should we do to let the Backpropagation work?

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: It also happened to me with a custom softplus activation function. The error appears to happen randomly, which can be overcome partially by setting a particular seed known to not cause the error before training the neural network.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and solved it by setting the `learningrate` to a 100-fold smaller value.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve this issue by using a very small learning rate. A good place to start would be something like 0.0001.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. The following worked with me:
Try to set `linear.output=F` and scale the output afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the fact the logistic function will always give you a value between -1 and 1. When using other smoothing functions, they may not have a maximum an/or minimum values. I don't know how to fix the problem, but it roots in the math behind neuralnet().

See more about those functions here:

https://jiafulow.github.io/blog/2019/07/11/softplus-and-softminus/