# neuralnet Error in while (step < stepmax && reached.threshold > threshold)

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to train a neural net to perform multiplication of two numbers. I do not want to use normalization. I am currently using the R package `neuralnet`, on RStudio. My complete relevant code is given below:

```
library(neuralnet)

# creating dataset
dataSize = 1000
datain <- data.frame(x1 = sample(1:dataSize) , x2 = sample(1:dataSize))
datain$y = datain$x1 * datain$x2

# splitting into train (80%) and test (20%) data
a = floor((0.8) * (dataSize)) 
dtrain <- datain[1:a , ] 
dtest <- datain[(a + 1):(dataSize) , ]  

# creating custom ReLU activation function
myActFunc = function(x) 
{
  log(1+exp(x))
}

#training NN 
a <- as.formula(paste("y ~ x1 + x2"))
f <- as.formula((a))

nn <- neuralnet(formula = f,
                data = as.matrix(dtrain),
                linear.output = TRUE,
                act.fct = myActFunc,
                hidden = c(4))
```

This results in the following error:

> Error in while (step < stepmax && reached.threshold > threshold) { :
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tweaking the stepmax, learningrate and threshold arguments changes the error to this:

> Error in if (reached.threshold < min.reached.threshold) { :
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318188/error-in-if-reached-threshold-min-reached-threshold-missing-value-wher), which has the second error I have, but it wasn't answered.

Please note that this is a regression problem, and I do not want to use normalization/scaling.

Comment: where is stepmax, learningrate and threshold variables defined?

Comment: can you change your activation to function, maybe to something standard like ramp or step and try once?

Comment: thank you for your response.

stepmax etc are all default currently. i.e.
threshold = 0.01, stepmax = 1e+05, learningrate = 0.01

i can't use step as this is a regression problem, and as i understand it, ramp is the same as ReLU? which is the one i have currently used.
Nonetheless, if i do change it, to eg logistic, it either does not converge, or gives extremely poor accuracy. In effect, doesn't really learn the function

Comment: but do you see the same error with different function?

Comment: I meant sigmoid or step

Comment: With sigmoid, it does not converge:

`algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax `